# web2py href and URL, gives wrong link

Tags: web2py

In view (for function "autotest") I have the following code:

```
{{link = URL(c ='static', f = 'files', args = [result[key].file_name], host = config.HOST)}}
link = {{=link}}
|
<a href="{{link}}"> href_link </a>
```

This is what I get in html page:

```
link = https://example.com/dwt/static/files/pdf.pdf | href_link
```

So far, so good. But behind the href_link there is:

`https://example.com/dwt/test/autotest`

Why is the static/files/pdf.pdf replaced with test/autotest?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{{=link}}`, not `{{link}}`. The latter doesn't actually write anything to the page, so the href ends up being empty, which the browser therefore defaults to the current page.

Comment: It's also not obvious what work the `link = {{=link}}` line is intended to do.

Comment: I assume that was for debugging purposes (of course, it didn't help because the correct syntax was used there).